# Send an app on the apple store

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode7

Hello I would like to send my app on the store. I already added a developer account and I always get the same error :  No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found but when i look the provisioning proviles list, it's not empty. (sorry for my english) 
Someone has a idea ?

Comment: Have you asked Apple?

Comment: No i didn't, I was using this [exporting your app for testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

Comment: If you have a specific programming problem ask us, otherwise, ask Apple

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general to answer. There are lots of reasons to your question. I think your problem maybe your Xcode does not download your profile yet or your project setting incorrect, or your profile setting is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some preparation before submitting to the Mac App Store, you need to set your bundle id in the developer portal, generate your provisioning profile and enter your app information in iTunes connect. Its a complicated process and you should provide more information about your specific problem. You can check Apple's documentation on how to distribute your app [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

Comment: it happen when i'm trying to create an archive